# Payara 5 @JMSConnectionFactory fails to inject when using @Stateless bean

Tags: java, jms, ejb, cdi, payara

I am testing out some JMS work on Paraya 5.  Specifically 5.181.  Below is the code for my simple Stateless bean.  `@JMSConnectionFactory` fails! the `JMSContext context` variable is always `null`.  However `@Resource(lookup = "jms/HelloWorldConnectionFactory")` succeeds...Any thoughts as to why?  I'd prefer to use `JMSContext`.

```
@Stateless
public class HelloWorldMessageSender {

    @JMSConnectionFactory("jms/HelloWorldConnectionFactory")
    protected JMSContext context;

    @Resource(lookup = "jms/HelloWorldConnectionFactory")
    protected ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(lookup = "jms/HelloWorldQueue")
    protected Queue queue;

    public String send() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SS");
        String txt = String.format("Hello world message %s", sdf.format(new Date()));
        if (context != null) {
            System.out.printf("Use JMSContext to produce%n");
            context.createProducer().send(queue, txt);
        }
        if (connectionFactory != null) {
            System.out.printf("Use ConnectionFactory to produce%n");
            try (
                Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            ) {
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
                message.setText(txt);
                producer.send(message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return txt;
    }
}
```

Just as a note, the `@Stateless` bean is being used inside of a JSF `@Named` bean. I'm using simple CDI injection to get the `@Stateless` bean, like this:

```
@Named(value = "helloWorldMessageController")
@RequestScoped
public class HelloWorldMessageController {

    @Inject
    protected HelloWorldMessageSender sender;

    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The annotation `@JMSConnectionFactory` has to be used with `@Inject` otherwise it doesn't have any effect. It just adds meta data for injection but doesn't cause any injection to happen.

It's clear from the example in the JMS 2.0 specification PDF:

`@Inject
@JMSConnectionFactory("jms/connectionFactory")
private JMSContext context;`

On the other hand, `@Resource` annotation is enough for injection because they are processed by the EJB container which handles them as injection point. So you should either use a single `@Resource` annotation or both `@Inject` and `@JMSConnectionFactory` together.

Comment: Ahhh!  You are so right.  I've been looking at the code too long and I just missed `@Inject`.  Cheers!

Comment: This one was easy, happy to have helped :)